# PHP > XML sorting trouble

Tags: php, xml, sorting, createfile

I am failing to corectly implement sorting in my PHP that creates xml list of my directory structure

```
   $dom = new DomDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');

   $root = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('list')); 
   foreach(array_keys($data_struct) as $key) {
      $category = $root->appendChild($dom->createElement('cat')); 
      $l1 = $category->appendChild($dom->createElement('l1'));

      $total = 0;
      foreach($data_struct[$key] as $value) {
         $l2 = $category->appendChild($dom->createElement('l2'));
         if ($value[1]>0) {
            $l2->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($value[0] . " (" . strval($value[1]) . ")"));
         }
         else {
            $l2->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($value[0]));
         }
         $total = $total + $value[1];
      }

      if ($total>0) {
         $l1->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($key . " (" . strval($total) . ")"));
      }
      else {
         $l1->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($key));
      }
   }
```

can anyone help me with proper sorting of my l1 and l2 elements?

Comment: Please read this first: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: It's unclear how the sorting is supposed to work and how it's incorrect at this point. Can you edit your question to add minimal examples of your source data, the incorrectly sorted output, and the way it should look when sorted correctly?